# How to change Android's default key press sound?

Tags: root-access, audio, file-system

The phone is rooted, I tried changing the file/s;

```
/system/media/audio/ui/*.ogg
```

and their permissions;

```
-rw-r--r--
```

but still plays the default. Restarting the phone doesn't work also.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you mean the sound the keyboard app makes, or the sound made when you have audio feedback for screen touches turned on? If the former, what keyboard app are you using?

Comment: @DanHulme I'm referring to the latter.